# How to access even elements of array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I want to echo the even elements of an array in bash, how could this be achieved?

Comment: While you are iterating over the array elements, test to see if the element is odd or even. So you'll have a `for` loop, and and `if` with an arithmetic expression. Which parts are having specific trouble with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about an indexed rather than associative array and you want the values for the even numbered indices rather than the even number values - loop from zero to array size incrementing the index by 2 on each iteration.

Borrowing @Camunsensei's example:

```
array=(a b c d e f g h)
for (( index=0; index<${#array[@]}; index+=2 )); do
    printf 'array[%d]=%q\n' "$index" "${array[index]}"
done
array[0]=a
array[2]=c
array[4]=e
array[6]=g
```

If that's not what you need then editing your question to include some sample input, expected output, and what you've tried so far would help a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your array is not sparse (contains no gaps),
Assuming by even you start counting from 1 (and not 0 like bash does), you can do that with a loop on the indexes:

```
array=(a b c d e f g h)
for index in "${!array[@]}"; do
  (( index % 2 )) && echo "${array[index]}"
done
:
```

outputs:

```
b
d
f
h
```